# Refer to other arguments in Powershell's ValidateScript

Tags: validation, powershell

I originally overcomplicated the question which I would like to now simplify:

Is it possible, and more importantly, officially supported by Microsoft for me to refer to parameters inside a ValidateScript section other than the parameter being validated?

Here is what I would like to do:

---

```
function test
{
    Param(
        [switch]
        $doThingA = $False,

        [ValidateScript({ 
            If( $doThingA -eq $True -and -not ( Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf ) )
            {
                Write-Output $False
            }

            Write-Output $True
        })]
        [string]
        $doThingA_FilePath
    )
}
```

This is what powershell's documentation states about the ValidateScript parameter

> When you use the ValidateScript attribute, the parameter value that is
>   being validated is mapped to the $_ variable. You can use the $_
>   variable to refer to the parameter value in the script.

Comment: Why the switches? Simply use the actual path parameters as indicator. If you need to ensure that at least one of them is set the simplest way is to check that inside the function body. Otherwise you have to resort to dynamic parameters.

Comment: I agree with Ansgar. Just test if the file paths are present and react to that.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a great idea. However, there may be other instances where I may want to validate a parameter that involves looking at the value of another parameter.

Comment: +1 learned something new... I knew about other ValidateXXX attributes but didn't know about `ValidateScript`

Answer (score 7):

You made me curious and I've run some tests. It seems that you can access other parameters' values inside a `ValidateScript` scriptblock, but only if they were already bound.

I.e. it all depends on order in which parameters were passed - your parameter with `ValidateScript` should be specified after all other parameters that you want to access inside the `ValidateScript` scriptblock.

Exception are:

- `Switch` parameters when binding by property name - in my tests they always return `false`.
- If your parameter with `ValidateScript` is using `ValueFromPipeline`, it seems that it's always bound last and so it can access all other parameters.

P.S. This is by no means a compete study, so feel free to experiment yourself.

Here is my test script:

```
function Test-ParamAccess
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [switch]$Alfa,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({
            'Output', [ordered]@{
                Alfa = $Alfa
                Bravo = $_
                Charlie = $Charlie
            } | Format-Table -Autosize | Out-String | Write-Warning
            $true
        })]
        [string]$Bravo,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Charlie
    )
}

$Cmdline = @(
     "-Alfa -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Charlie 'CHARLIE'",
     "-Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Bravo 'BRAVO'",
     "-Bravo 'BRAVO' -Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE'",
     "-Bravo 'BRAVO' -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa",
     "-Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa -Bravo 'BRAVO'",
     "-Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Alfa"
)

$Hashtable = @(
      'Alfa = $true ; Bravo = "BRAVO" ; Charlie = "CHARLIE" ;'
      'Alfa = $true ; Charlie = "CHARLIE" ; Bravo = "BRAVO" ;'
      'Bravo = "BRAVO" ; Alfa = $true ; Charlie = "CHARLIE" ;'
      'Bravo = "BRAVO" ; Charlie = "CHARLIE" ; Alfa = $true ;'
      'Charlie = "CHARLIE" ; Alfa = $true ; Bravo = "BRAVO" ;'
      'Charlie = "CHARLIE" ; Bravo = "BRAVO" ; Alfa = $true ;'
) | ForEach-Object {
  Invoke-Expression "[ordered]@{$_}"
}

$Pipeline = @(
    "-Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE'",
    "-Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa"
)

$Separator =  '=' * 80

$Separator, 'Arguments via commandline:', $Separator | Write-Host
$Cmdline | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Input: $_"
    Invoke-Expression "Test-ParamAccess $_"
}

$Separator, 'Arguments via splatting:', $Separator | Write-Host
$Hashtable | ForEach-Object {
    'Input:', ($_ | Out-String) | Write-Host
    Test-ParamAccess @_
}

$Separator, 'Arguments via pipeline by property name:', $Separator | Write-Host
$Hashtable | ForEach-Object {
    'Input:', ($_ | Out-String) | Write-Host
    New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $_ | Test-ParamAccess
}

$Separator, 'Arguments via pipeline by value:', $Separator | Write-Host 
$Pipeline | ForEach-Object {
    'Input:', ($_ | Out-String) | Write-Host
    Invoke-Expression "'BRAVO' | Test-ParamAccess $_"
}
```

And result:

```
================================================================================
Arguments via commandline:
================================================================================
Input: -Alfa -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Charlie 'CHARLIE'
WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa    True 
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input: -Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Bravo 'BRAVO'
WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input: -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE'
WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa         
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input: -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa
WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa         
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input: -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa -Bravo 'BRAVO'
WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input: -Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Bravo 'BRAVO' -Alfa
WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa           
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


================================================================================
Arguments via splatting:
================================================================================
Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              


WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa    True 
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              


WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa         
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 


WARNING: Output


Name    Value
----    -----
Alfa         
Bravo   BRAVO
Charlie      


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa           
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


================================================================================
Arguments via pipeline by property name:
================================================================================
Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
Charlie                        CHARLIE                                                                                                                                              
Bravo                          BRAVO                                                                                                                                                
Alfa                           True                                                                                                                                                 


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    False  
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


================================================================================
Arguments via pipeline by value:
================================================================================
Input:
-Alfa -Charlie 'CHARLIE'


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE


Input:
-Charlie 'CHARLIE' -Alfa


WARNING: Output


Name    Value  
----    -----  
Alfa    True   
Bravo   BRAVO  
Charlie CHARLIE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was trying to get [switch] to work, but I guess it's just broken in my current version of powershell.  Maybe in the future it'll be fixed?  Maybe there's a workaround?